# Проверить значение в таблице SQL

Tags: sql, joomla, joomla3

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как проверить и получить строки по колонке *rules*, например значение 6. Честно говоря я впервые вижу такую запись. Это действительно массив в ячейке?

[image: Это массив в ячейке?]

Comment: Можно попробовать обработать с помощью JSON для SQL. Т.е. получить нужные данные и потом отдельно извлекать оттуда значения

Comment: можно попробовать так `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE CONCAT(',', rules, ',') LIKE '%,6,%'` но это будет не совсем правильно

Comment: @SLideR11 А какой тип у этой колонки?

Comment: @Sterlukin, строковый. Поэтому я пока сделал через LIKE, но предпочёл бы переделать.